# AppCompact ListView CAB not showing

Tags: android, listview, android-appcompat

I am trying to make my listview use multiple select feature. I have followed a couple of tutorials and came up with the code below. For some reason I can't get the CAB to show and I'm wondering what am I doing wrong here.

This is the function in which I try to set the listview multi selectable and where I try to inflate the CAB

```
public void loadGroupSchedule(final int gid) {
        SUBLEVEL = 1;
        CustomListViewValuesArrSchedules.clear();
//        list.notify();
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewCustom);
        list.setAdapter(null);

        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

        list.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

            }
        });

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SERVER_SCHEDULES, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
            ... //too much code, deleted it from here
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (SUBLEVEL != 5) {
                    hideLoading();
                    list.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    ISVU.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    noInternet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Button retry = (Button) findViewById(R.id.noInternetBtn);

                    retry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            noInternet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            loadGroupSchedule(gid);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("groupid", String.valueOf(gid));

                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                //params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return new HashMap<String, String>();
            }
        };
        showLoading();
        queue.add(sr);

    }
```

This is my listview item layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/classItemLV"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:elevation="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lday"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minWidth="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="P\nO\nN"
            android:id="@+id/DAY1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lTime"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lday">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="10"
            android:id="@+id/timeFrom"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLV3Dark" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="12"
            android:id="@+id/timeTo"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLV3Dark"
            android:layout_below="@+id/timeFrom" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lInfo"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/lTime">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Analiza financijskih izvještaja"
            android:id="@+id/className"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLV3Dark"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="prof. dr. sc. Ivan Ivić"
            android:id="@+id/classTutor"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLV3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/className" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="PREDAVANJE - DV41"
            android:id="@+id/classTypePlace"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLV3"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/classTutor" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Datum: 5.10.-25.1."
            android:id="@+id/classDate"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLV3"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/classTypePlace"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my listview

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listViewCustom"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

And this is my menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/test_id"
        android:title="test"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_chick" />
</menu>
```

I am using a custom adapter for the listview, could that be an issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Im sorry, maybe, I lost smth. But you call `list.setAdapter(null);` and I can't find where you set a not null adapter.

Comment: It's called, I just commented it out due to the length of code. The listview shows rows correctly

Comment: Do u use `Toolbar` like `ActionBar`?

Comment: Yes I am using one, why?

Comment: Read [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483778/display-actionmode-over-toolbar)

Comment: I think that it doesn't call an action mode in the `Toolbar`. You can call it manually. Sorry, I haven't a studio now to analyze your code.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll look into it. At least I'm on some track now, thanks mate

Comment: @Шах Thank you thank you thank you thank you :)
I've spent 3 hours searching and going crazy, thanks to your answer I've done it all in 10 minutes! Please post it as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Sorry, I type from my phone it's hard... But I glad that it helped you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, the listener can not call an action mode in the `Toolbar`.
Read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483778/display-actionmode-over-toolbar) to call it manually.